# Android Program request permissions

Tags: android

I am trying to use GPS in android but it gives me this error:

[image]

I put in manifest these permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

can anyone help me please

Comment: In the latest android versions we can able to restrict the permissions there are two kinds of permissions normal and secure  Location manager service comes under secure permission you need to check it user allowed to acces the permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the hint suggests : The user may deny permission. In that case this call will throw error...

Right now, android asks for the user to accept all the permissions an app asks for in the manifest on installation. In the upcoming M release, android will switch over to the iOS style of permissions with an "on needed" basis.

Call this method to see if permission is granted or not. If not, you need to handle that situation.

```
context.checkCallingPermission(permission)
```

Declaring permission in manifest only means that you are requesting permission. In new releases it will not guarantee that user will give you that permission.

In older releases the user has to accept all or reject all permissions

Comment: So as you said that means , the program will work properly and will not work if the user didn't allow application to use Gps or network. but the application stopped when i run it on the emulator where the GPS access is enabled

Comment: @Saleh923 Yes, in case the user denies permission the app may crash. 
Please check what was the reason of crash on emulator ... may be it was due to a different issue !

By the way check if your emulator can emulate GPS / Network ..
Best is to test on device

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error actually but a heads-up by the Lint and which may cause an issue!

Hope you are aware about the new permission model is introduced in Android 6.0 (Marshmallow), through which user may not permit to use GPS or Network or anything else and so it may cause an issue in your application!

Now, as per the lint analysis, so before implementing particular functionality, you should check whether permission for the same is available or not!

Comment: So as you said that means , the program will work properly and will not work if the user didn't allow application to use Gps or network. but the application stopped when i run it on the emulator where the GPS access is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Since SDK 23, you should/need to check the permission using checkSelfPermission

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html

for example

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This condition checks user allowed to access the permission to read the location

```
if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED||checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,meter,mill,new locationlist(this));
}
```